# How do I update when using a development release?

Tags: updates, release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the recommended method for getting & installing updates for an Ubuntu (alpha or) beta release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118603/what-is-the-recommended-method-for-getting-installing-updates-for-an-ubuntu-a)

I've installed 11.10 Alpha2 in a virtual machine (Virtualbox). I know there are updates since i installed it, about a week ago, but when i try `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it doesn't find any updates.

So my question, is there any special way for upgrading alpha releases? What about betas?